# Python zeep : AttributeError: 'lxml.etree.QName' object has no attribute 'resolve'

Tags: python, soap, wsdl, attributeerror, zeep

I have just installed ‘zeep’ (used suds before), with the command:

> pip install lxml==3.7.3 zeep

I am getting the error:

```
self.item_type = self.item_type.resolve()
AttributeError: 'lxml.etree.QName' object has no attribute 'resolve'
```

The same wsdl loads correctly using netbeans JAX-WS Web Services.

Comment: hi! Did you find a solution for you issue, even if it's a bit old now? I am figuring the same.